# devise_invitable customize invite link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise-invitable

I'm using devise_invitable for inviting users through mail. when users follow the link it redirects to set password page which i don't want.

How to send an invitation with a link to my customized page?

i tried overriding controller

```
class InvitationsController < Devise::InvitationsController
```

added views via generate. [i can edit invitation page] devise/mailer/invitation_instructions.

```
accept_invitation_url(@resource, :invitation_token => @token)
```

modified devise.rb to include my controller. but my controller is not used and it uses devise's controller.

```
devise_for :candidates, :controller => {:invitations => 'invitations'}
```

I want this to be customized link. How to change the flow and override controller?

Comment: generate devise view and then modify the page according to your need

Comment: I did it! but how to pass the parameters to the view? the link?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect your invitee to your custom page,
you can specify it by overriding `after_invite_path_for(resource)`

Answer (score 0):

Are you using devise_invitable gem?

If so, I think it uses custom code to include routes and you need to add your modified routes before devise.

```
resource :invitation, only: [:new, :create], path: '...', controller: '...'
```

You can refer to this file to get some ideas on how to override routes: https://github.com/scambra/devise_invitable/blob/master/lib/devise_invitable/routes.rb

Hope it helps!